# How to delete text from a text file via batch

Tags: batch-file, text, find

Have looked about the web but cant find anything that can help. I am trying to make a page that can delete something of a page. Have managed to make a search that can tell you if a word is on the .txt file. How would I put it into this?

```
cls
set /p SEARCH= Please enter what you want to look for?

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (

set FIND=%%a

)

if %SEARCHS%==%FIND% goto FLIGHT HAS ARRIVED
echo We were not able to find %SEARCH%
pause
goto start
```

Does anybody know what I should do?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

```
type file|find "string in lines to remove" /i /v >newfile
```

might help.

`set /p reg=text:`
`for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do if %%a'==%reg%' goto found`
I can't tell what you want to do though so if this doesn't help please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
set /p "SEARCH= Please enter what you want to look for? "
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('find "%SEARCH%" test.txt') do set "FOUND=%%a"
if DEFINED FOUND goto FLIGHT_HAS_ARRIVED
echo We were not able to find %SEARCH%
pause
goto start

:FLIGHT_HAS_ARRIVED
ECHO %SEARCH% found: %FOUND%
goto:eof
```

You shouldn't use cmd command names for variable names (`%FIND%`). 
Jump labels do not work as expected, if it contain spaces: `FLIGHT HAS ARRIVED`